# Sequelize Eager Loading Nested Where Error

Tags: sequelize.js

I have four tables involved in my sql query, (`document`, `user`, `organization`, `organization_member` (Junction Table). The relationships involved with these tables are as follows:

**User to Org.**
`User.belongsToMany(db.Organization, { through: 'organization_member', foreignKey: 'user_id'})`

**Org. to User**
`Organization.belongsToMany(db.User, { through: 'organization_member', foreignKey: 'organization_id'})`

**Document to User**
`Document.belongsTo(db.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id'})`

---

**Now with my query**, I am first querying my documents, ordering by a date field on the document, `documentDate or document_date` and limiting by 10 records.

```
models.Document.findAll({
        attributes: ['documentDate', 'title', 'discovery'],
        order: [[ sequelize.col('documentDate'), 'DESC']],
        limit: 10,
        ...
})
```

**From there,** I am including my `user` model and then nesting within the `user` model include, the `organization` model and filtering (where clause) for only those documents that belong to a user within the organization that set to the session.

```
models.Document.findAll({
    ...
    include: [{
                model: models.User,
                attributes: ['userId', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'picture'],
                include: [{
                    model: models.Organization,
                    where: { organizationId: req.session.organizationId },
                    attributes: ['organizationName']
                }]
            }]
```

})

**At this point, I receive an error:**

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column user.userid does not exist
```

Which is bizarre because that column exists as `userId` or `user_id`.

```
userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field:'user_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
```

when I throw it into Postgres to check out where the error is coming from, it is line 25. Code also here: https://pastebin.com/awsmEDfc

Could this be a bug that happens when you use a `where` clause on an include?

Full code:

```
models.Document.findAll({
        attributes: ['documentDate', 'title', 'discovery'],
        order: [[ sequelize.col('documentDate'), 'DESC']],
        limit: 10,
        include: [{
            model: models.User,
            attributes: ['userId', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'picture'],
            include: [{
                model: models.Organization,
                where: { organizationId: req.session.organizationId },
                attributes: ['organizationName']
            }]
        }]
})
```